# Throughput drops after saturation with more threads

Tags: cuda

Theoretically, when the number of threads in SM increases until it reaches the peak throughput, the throughput is supposed to be saturated, meaning further increasing the threads, no acceleration gain and the throughput line should be flat.

The kernel is as follows:

```
#pragma unroll UNROLL
for( int i = 0; i < N_ITERATIONS; i++ )
{ 
a = a * b + a;
}
```

However, the throughput of this kernel drops after reaching maximum throughput. The number of warps reach the maximum throughput (7.9 ops/clock) is 6 warps. I wondered what factors impact throughput drops after 6 warps. The GPU is Tesla C1060 and all the warps are in one single block.

Thanks in advance for your time and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tesla architecture a warp can issue an instruction every 4 scheduling cycles so at least 4 warps are required to hide latency. Some dependent instruction latency and fetch latency can require additional warps to hide latency. The referenced kernel is a chain of dependent ALU instructions that quickly issues through instruction RAM. Adding more warps is likely to put pressure on the fetch unit. Usually long latency memory instructions relieve the fetch unit.